# upload file to folder on device, filesharing ios

Tags: ios, directory, file-sharing

im using filesharing in my app, working fine, but I want now for organization to be able to upload files from itunes to app folder

the itunes lets me import a file "Add", but i cannot drag the file to the created folder in my file system or "Add" in my folder,

- so how can i upload the images to the specified folder in the device?
- or do I have to dynamically check for the content of the /documents/ content and move the file to the wanted folder??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add files via iTunes to the documents directory. You can either create your own AFP or WebDAV server on the iPhone and connect to it like a network drive (you have to code the server yourself). Alternatively you can check for new items in the documents directory as you suggested yourself and move them to wherever you want. Bear in mind that if you move them from the documents directory you will not be able to access them through iTunes once moved. Why don't you just store them in the documents directory anyway?

Comment: hi thanks, i will use the folder to have some data that the user shouldn't mess with (only able to download) and the root for the user uploaded pics, thanks again ;)